# Select value between comma and parentheses in PHP

Tags: php, regex, extract

I have

```
$string = "sw $t4, -16($t2)";
```

How do I extract the `-16`?  I'm having a lot of trouble trying to get the regular expressions to work.

Comment: Can you post the regex that you currently have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this expression: `/,(.*?)\(/s`

Answer (score 0):

Or, without a regex:

```
$start  = strpos( $string, ',') + 1;
$end = strlen( $string) - strpos( $string, '(') - 1;
$number = substr( $string, $start, $end);
```

Or, another way using `strstr()`:

```
$number = substr( strstr( strstr( $string, ','), '(', true), 1);
```